# How to perform a query of jsonb top-level values in key/value pairs in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

If I have data stored in a `jsonb` column like the following...

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2", "value2", ...., "keyN", "valueN"}
```

How can I do an `ilike` query on the values which are all strings? Basically looking for ...

```
select * from <table> where jsonb_col.top_level_value ilike '%xxx%';
```

Is this possible?  Cheers.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: postgres version 10.15

Answer (score 3):

If you know in advance that the values are all strings, you can use a function like `jsonb_each_text`.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM <table>, jsonb_each_text(jsonb_col) x 
WHERE x.value ILIKE '%xxx%';
                       jsonb_col                        | key  |      value
--------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------
 {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "keyN": "valxxx"} | keyN | valxxx
(1 row)
```

But be warned that if you have values that are not strings, they will be treated as strings anyway. To ignore the non-string values, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM <table>, jsonb_each(jsonb_col) x 
WHERE x.value::text ILIKE '%xxx%'
AND jsonb_typeof(x.value) = 'string';
                       jsonb_col                        | key  |      value
--------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------
 {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "keyN": "valxxx"} | keyN | "valxxx"
(1 row)
```

Comment: Perfect! Forgot to mention that the values were all strings, but they are indeed strings and this works a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: To exclude non-string values, lateral join into both `jsonb_each_text()` and `jsonb_each()`, and use `jsonb_typeof() = 'string'` on the `value` from `jsonb_each()`.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeOrganek, I adjusted the answer accordingly.